# Scaling column values between 0 and 1 in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table called table1 with following columns:-

```
ID  count1  count2
A   3       5
B   1       7
C   2       9
```

I need the columns - count1 and count2 to have values between 0 and 1. I need to perform this in hive to size of data. The final table should look like this:-

```
ID  count1  count2
A   1       0
B   0       0.5
C   0.5     1
```

I write the following query:-

```
select a.ID, 
(((a.count1-min(a.count1))/(max(a.count1)-min(a.count1))),
(((a.count2-min(a.count2))/(max(a.count2)-min(a.count2)))
from table1 as a;
```

This query gives me a group by error with respect to column ID.

Please assist in performing this operation in hiveql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using `min` and `max` window functions. An empty `over()` clause calculates the aggregation for all values in the column. As window functions are not aggregate functions, there is no need to `group by`.

```
select ID, 
(count1-min(count1) over())/(max(count1) over()-min(count1) over()),
(count2-min(count2) over())/(max(count2) over() -min(count2) over())
from table1
```